# GoJS Html Context Menu - Get SelectedNode

Tags: gojs

I am trying to get selected Node when I right-click on a Node using HTML menu context.

HTML Code:

```
<li id="detail" onclick="cxcommand(event, 'detail')"><a href="#">Details</a></li>
<li id="disconnect" onclick="cxcommand(event, 'disconnect')"><a href="#">Disconnect</a></li>
<li id="remove" onclick="cxcommand(event, 'remove')"><a href="#">Remove</a></li>
```

JS Code:

```
// This is the general menu command handler, parameterized by the name of the command.
function cxcommand(event, val) {

    // var selectedNode = myDiagram.findPartAt(myDiagram.toolManager.contextMenuTool.currentObject);

    myDiagram.currentTool.stopTool();
}
```

How can I get the selected Node from HTML Context menu?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the sample https://gojs.net/latest/samples/customContextMenu.html, the `cxcommand` function being called by a click on a context menu item gets a reference to the **Diagram** via a global variable, in this case `myDiagram`:

```
    function cxcommand(event, val) {
      if (val === undefined) val = event.currentTarget.id;
      var diagram = myDiagram;
      switch (val) {
        case "cut": diagram.commandHandler.cutSelection(); break;
        . . .
```

Alternatively you could have the function called by the `onclick` be a closure that keeps a reference to the **Diagram**.

Once you have the diagram, the **Diagram.selection** property gets you the currently selected Parts.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the object by calling **myDiagram.selection.first()**. Thanks to GoJS support team.

```
 function cxcommand(event, val) {     

      var selectedNode = myDiagram.selection.first();
      // ---- more code here

     switch (val) {
     case "detail": commandDetail(selectedNode);break;
     case "disconnect": commandDisconnect(selectedNode);break;
     case "remove": commandRemove(selectedNode);break;
     }

  }
```